# Having trouble understanding custom post type and taxonomy :/

Tags: custom-post-types, taxonomy

I am developing a Wordpress site that will have a database of car modifications and an embedded youtube video with the results.

For example: search for Honda Civic with a spoiler and exhaust. This would generate several posts. Each post has there own video, attributes, and an adsense ad. I am using the term posts loosely though, I really don't want to post them on the blog of the site.

I am struggling to see how (if) this can work with the custom post type and taxonomy features in 3.0.

Also I found this $200 theme on WooThemes, I'm not positive it will work and they wont talk to me about technical stuff unless i'm a "member". I would Like to insert youtube videos instead of their dealer listing, but it seems like the theme is a great start.

[WooThemes - "Listings"](http://www.woothemes.com/2010/12/listings/)

Thanks for any help and insight, I am at my wits end try to see if this is do-able.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Register a 'car' [post type](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types).
2. Register 'spoiler' and 'exhaust' [taxonomies](http://codex.wordpress.org/Taxonomies) to the 'car' post type.
3. Use the [Taxonomy Drill-Down](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/query-multiple-taxonomies/) plugin to create the "search" you need.

The YouTube video URL could be stored as a [custom field](http://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Fields).

Comment: Thanks i'll have to look further into this. I'm setting up a test server this weekend, hopefully I can get something working. Also, using the above example, would this query include Porsche and mustang spoilers? I am hoping it would only search the post type (Civic, Accord,etc...). I am still testing, it seems all of the tutorials focus on products.

Comment: I wish I could vote up your answer, I will check back when I have 15 points :) Thanks again!